# Using a scheduled timer to repeatedly fire an animation in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, animation

I use this code to create and run the timer, which works OK.

```
NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 6.0];
NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                              interval: 6
                              target: self
                              selector:@selector(startAnimation)
                              userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

My startAnimation method just contains

```
[myUIImageView startAnimating];
```

The method does run every six seconds, but the animation runs once and does not repeat.

Any ideas why this is happening?

---

Edit. My animation is set up like this:

```
-(void) setUpAnimation{
    myUIImageView  =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.animatedView.frame];
    myUIImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                   nil];


myUIImageView.animationDuration = 3;
myUIImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

//add the animation view to the main window;
[self.view addSubview:myUIImageView];  

}
```

As I said above, this works fine just once, but then does not repeat! 
Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code above......it probably has something to do with your animation code. Could you post that?

Comment: Could you provide the code for the animation?

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper Added to the OP! Cheers.

Comment: @BerndRabe Done! Cheers.

Comment: Did you check that your myUIImageView is still existing when you send your startAnimating?

Comment: I've just run that code in a demo project and it works fine. Like @BerndRabe was saying, are you sure that the image view is still there when you call startAnimating again??

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper The image view still exists, yes. And it does get to the `startAnimating` line (and runs it without errors) but the animation only actually displays on the screen once.

Comment: I honestly don't know what it could be. Because I've copied and pasted that code in too my own project and it works fine every time. Are you referencing that image view somewhere else in you code?

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper Nope! OK, I just set it up in a totally new project and it STILL only runs once! What am I doing differently to you? Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/JzMKBUHE (edit: wait, sometimes it runs once, sometimes it runs at seemingly random intervals)

Comment: OK so the only different thing I do compared to you is...I've defined myUIImageView in the interface....I've also tried the same way as you and it doesn't make any difference. And when you initialise the image view you initialise it with self.animatedView.frame?? What is that view and where does it get referenced??

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper animatedView is just the UIImageView which is on the storyboard. `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedView;` in the ViewController's header file. If that makes sense.

Comment: Is the animatedView a subview of your controllers view? Define your myUIImageView like so @property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *myUIImageView;

Comment: @BerndRabe Nah, does the same thing :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startAnimating` starts the animation that is set up to run one time. You never stop the animation, so sending a second `startAnimating` does nothing. Try:

```
-(void)startAnimation {
    [myUIImageView stopAnimating];
    [myUIImageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Jesus. I knew it'd be something this simple. You are a genius and I am an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. Try to be as decent as possible with your objects.